# Evaluating $\int^{x_2} _{x_1} \sqrt{a - b x^m} ~dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

Is there any way to evaluate 
$$\int^{x_2} _{x_1} \sqrt{(a - b x^m)}~ dx $$
where $x_{12} = \pm (a/b)^{1/m}$
without elliptic functions or hypergeometry? Or just any way to solve it. My attempt is to substitute 
$x = (a/b)^{1/m} \sin u$, $dx = (a/b)^{1/m} \cos u ~du $, $u = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. The initial expression then equals
$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}} _{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \Big (\frac{a}{b}\Big)^{\frac{1}{m}} \sqrt{a (1-\sin^m u)}~ dx $$
It worked good before, when $m = 2$, but now it does not seem do help. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: In general, for positive values of *m* and *n* we have $$\int_0^1\sqrt[n]{1-x^m}~dx~=~\int_0^1\sqrt[m]{1-x^n}~dx ~=~ {m^{-1}+n^{-1}\choose n^{-1}}^{-1}~=~{m^{-1}+n^{-1}\choose n^{-1}}^{-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Try substituting $x=(a/b)^{1/m} y^{1/m}$. This should reduce it to a multiple of an integral of the form
$$ \int_{A}^B y^{k} (1-y)^n \, dy, $$
which can be at least partially computed using the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying it out now